# Name of divergence $D(p||q) = \max_x {p(x) - q(x)}$

Tags: probability, distributions, distance-functions

$D(p||q) = \max_x {p(x) - q(x)}$ is thought of as a very simple divergence for two continuous probability distributions.

This satisfies minimum requirements of divergence, $D(p||q)\ge0$ and $D(p||q)=0$ (if and only if $p(x)=q(x)$).

I wanna know the name of this divergence to learn more properties of this divergence. Or what family of divergences does this belong to?

Of course, I already googled for hours with keywords like divergences and distance metrics but could not found any information.